# Почему amocrm не пропускает русский домен в интеграции

Tags: crm

Пытаюсь настроить интеграцию в amocrm для сборка заявок с сайта, но застрял на том что redirect_uri:

1. не пропускает домен франшиза.хинкалыч.рф - он его не находит.
2. пытался через пуни код https:// xn--80aaudyq1a9a.xn--80apgfh0ct5a.xn--p1ai - страничка вовсе виснет, но даже если подождать то uri не валиден

Помогите разобраться в чем дело. Спасибо

Comment: пингуется нормально. `sudo traceroute -i eth0 "франшиза.хинкалыч.рф"` => `10.1.66.158 (10.1.66.158)  40.697 ms  39.116 ms  40.448 ms`

Comment: Как мне сказали гуру амо срм это проблема кириллического домена, скорее всего нужно будет создавать зеркало с нормальным доменом, так что вопрос закрыт